# update the text of a listView row

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want my listView to be updated after clicking on a row (or any event, but let's focus on click).

I did something, but it updates more than one row (maybe it updates the first visible row and the one after the last visible...).
Here is the full code

**Activity code**

```
DatabaseHandler colisageBase;
ListView listView;
List<Site> sites;
String id_tournee;
SiteAdapter siteAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_site_choice);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    id_tournee = intent.getStringExtra("idTourneeSelectionnee");
    this.listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view_site);
    this.colisageBase = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    sites = colisageBase.selectAllSite(id_tournee);
    siteAdapter = new SiteAdapter(SiteChoiceActivity.this, sites);
    listView.setAdapter(siteAdapter);
    colisageBase.closeDB();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Site selectedSite = sites.get(position);
            selectedSite.setIsBarred(true);
            sites.set(position, selectedSite);
            siteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //goToOperationActivity(selectedSite.SiteOut());
        }
    });
```

**Adapter code**

```
public class SiteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Site> {

public SiteAdapter(Context context, List<Site> sites) {
    super(context, 0, sites);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_site,parent, false);
    }

    SiteViewHolder viewHolder = (SiteViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    if(viewHolder == null){
        viewHolder = new SiteViewHolder();
        viewHolder.heure_supposee = convertView.findViewById(R.id.heure_supposee);
        viewHolder.libelle_site = convertView.findViewById(R.id.libelle_site);
        viewHolder.logo_telephone = convertView.findViewById(R.id.logo_phone);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    Site site = getItem(position);

    viewHolder.heure_supposee.setText(site.getHeure_supposee());
    viewHolder.libelle_site.setText(site.getLibelle_site());
    viewHolder.logo_telephone.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if (site.getSur_appel().equals("O")) viewHolder.logo_telephone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (site.isBarred()) viewHolder.libelle_site.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged()
{
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class SiteViewHolder{
    public TextView heure_supposee;
    public TextView libelle_site;
    public ImageView logo_telephone;
}
```

}

Please suggest what's wrong with the code.

Comment: Post full code SiteAdapter and Activity pls:

Comment: You should using recyclerview, and recyclerview Adapter

Comment: hi, I just put full code, i don't know how recyclerview adapter works, i'm going to read more about it, do you have any link related to the subject ?

Comment: Try this: in onclick
  sites.get(position).setIsBarred(true);
    siteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: it's still not working

Comment: Why call `sites.set(position, selectedSite);`? You just retrieved `Site` from the same position.

Comment: Also are you sure `Sites` contains unique object references. Try logging the entire list (reference number and object member values) in `SiteAdapter`'s constructor, where list is provided.

Comment: Try adding `listView.invalidateViews()` after you notify the adapter

Comment: Hi, I added listView.invalidateViews() but nothing has changed, and yes my list contains unique object references Abbas

Comment: Try inside getView(), add **else** condition for both `if(site...`. Hope that helps!

Comment: waw it works ! thank you

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given in the comments by I_A_Mok, but i have to add more details:

In the case of a cell, when you do an action in an "if" condition , you usually have to do the opposite in an "else" condition.

In my case, after my condition where I strike through text, I had to add an else condition where I don't strike through text.

```
if (site.isBarred()){
        viewHolder.libelle_site.setPaintFlags(viewHolder.libelle_site.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    }else {
        viewHolder.libelle_site.setPaintFlags(viewHolder.libelle_site.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
    }
```